# Resolving circular (recursive) component dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, circular-dependency

I have a case in which I need to create two components: a MultiField component and a MultiFieldItem component. Now, a MultiField component's structure is similar to something like this:

```js
export const MultiField = ({arrayOfData}) => {
    return <div>
      <div> some other stuff </div>
      <div> {arrayOfData.map((element) => <MultiFieldItem data={element}/>)} </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the thing is that in general, a MultiFieldItem *might* contain a whole MultiField as well, imagine something like this:

```js
export const MultiFieldItem = ({data}) => {
    return <div>
      <div> some stuff </div>
      <div> some other stuff </div>
      <div> {arrayOfData.map((element) => <MultiField data={data}/>)} </div>
    </div>
```

Which obviously creates a circular dependency and crashes my app. How would I get around this issue?

Comment: Do they really need to be separate components in separate files?

Comment: @morganney Seperate components - yes, seperate files - not exactly

Comment: Typically I follow [this](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) article until one of the methods works. Have you tried the "internal module" pattern?